# Perl http post request: Attempt to use reference as lvalue in substr

Tags: perl, httprequest, httpclient

I am using `HTTP::Tiny` to do a sample http client (only get and post requests). `GET` requests are working fine but I have an issue when I try to do a `POST` request. Here is the code:

```
sub postRequest {
    my %params = @_;
    my $url= "http://localhost:3001/Perform";
    my %opt;
    $opt{content} = \%params;
    my $http = HTTP::Tiny->new();
    my $response = $http->request("POST", $url, \%opt);

    # my $response = $http->post($url, {content => \%params}); # not working too

    unless ($response->{success}) {
        die "Unsuccessful request to " . $url. "\n";
    }

    print "response: " . $response->{content} . "\n";
    return $response->{content};
}
```

Where `%params` hash is like `{ key1 => "val1", key2 => "val2" }`. The message I get is `Attempt to use reference as lvalue in substr at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/HTTP/Tiny.pm line 806, <STDIN> line 7.` and I have not idea how to resolve it.

Comment: You can try `post_form` method which I think you can pass the params as hashref.

[post_form](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/HTTP-Tiny-0.058/lib/HTTP/Tiny.pm#post_form)

I didn't try the code, sorry.

Comment: @ZaferK what is the value of `$form_data`?

Comment: as far as I understand from the documentation.

`$form_data = { key1 => "val1", key2 => "val2" };
$response = $http->post_form($url, $form_data);`

This might work for POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you actually want:

```
$http->post_form($url, \%params);
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`HTTP::Tiny::request`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edagolden/HTTP-Tiny-0.058/lib/HTTP/Tiny.pm#request) allow for a hash reference `\%options`

> ```
> $response = $http->request($method, $url, \%options);
> ```

and for its keys say the following

> Valid options are:
>
> - headers [ ... ]
> - content — A scalar to include as the body of the request OR a code reference that will be called iteratively to produce the body of the request

This means that the `content` key should have a value which is either a scalar (string), or a code reference.  The value for `content` in your code is a hash reference, `\%params`.

Change it to a string or a code reference.